# question about querySelectorAll declaration

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'm taking a course that uses the queryselectorall tool, and I was a doubt about his statement! The space between **.seat.selected** produces the desired effect

```
function updateSelectedCount() {
    const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected')
    const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length
    console.log(selectedSeatsCount)
}
```

But if I put a space between them,nothing happens

```
function updateSelectedCount() {
    const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat .selected')
    const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length
    console.log(selectedSeatsCount)
}
```

the space between classes does what in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is looking for something like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="seat selected">
```

where the 2nd is

```
<div class="row">
<div class="seat">
<div class="selected">
```

Answer (score 2):

`.seat.selected` that mean two class .seat and .selected in only `one div`

`.seat .selected` that mean div .seat is `parent` of div .selected